# Insert 7M rows with/without indices

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which I need to insert 7M rows. If I do it without indices, it takes just a few seconds. However, if I do it with indices, it takes several minutes. Is there a way of inserting the rows without using the index but being able to use it when querying the table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect the database to use an index if the data has not been inserted into it?

Comment: If you don't need to query the table during the insertion process there can be an approach to disable indexes before loading (mark unusable), then inserting the data, then rebuilding the indexes back (alter index rebuild + optional parallel). In some cases this will be faster than loading data into the table with enabled indexes.
Also you may consider to disable indexes, constraints and triggers on the table, then inserting using direct path insert (with append hint), and then enabling all that back.

Comment: @Dornaut thanks a lot. Could you please provide an example so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Indexes don't normally slow down inserts *that* much. Do you have any unusual index types, like a bitmap index or a function based index with a slow function? You may only need to disable one of your indexes, or maybe there's an issue with the way you're inserting; are you inserting one row at a time or in batches?

Comment: You can disable the index, insert all the data, and finally enable the index again. The last step will take a few extra seconds, but it should be faster than inserting with the index included. All this, assuming your application can live without the index for a short period of time.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanka a lot. Could you please post an example on how to do that so I can acceot the answer if that's ok?